# Positioning a span inside a relatively positioned div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a Wordpress plugin and I've come across a problem with positioning a `span`. Basically, there's a `div` that holds an `img` and a `span` (the `div` and `span` are added dynamically in the plugin, but I don't think that's the case here) that should cover the `img`. The size, float and margins of that `span` are set dynamically once the image is loaded, so the `span` covers the image entirely.

Unfortunately, when the `image` is floated right, has a positive margin-left value and is wider (image+margin) than the `div` that contains it, there's a problem. The left margin of the `image` is altered, but the `span`'s left margin isn't, so the `span` doesn't cover the image properly. Is there a way to fix this issue or a good workaround? I mean in a way that will work well in other cases, like floating the image left, etc. I've noticed that it works similarly on Chrome, IE9 and FF19.

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/6zQp3/1/

**UPDATE**
I don't think I've explained the issue well enough, so here's another example:

http://jsfiddle.net/6zQp3/53/

I've pointed out which parts of the code I can change and which I can't. Basically, the plugin dynamically creates the `div.image-container` and `span.cover` (I've omitted this part here, as it's not really relevant) for every image on the site. The `span.cover` should cover the image entirely. As you can see in this new example, the first image isn't covered properly, while others are. That's my issue - adjusting the JavaScript and maybe css so it'll work properly in this one case as well. Please note that I cannot modify css of images (so using absolute positioning on images isn't an option).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but could you do this? http://jsfiddle.net/6zQp3/2/

Comment: @Matthew: Thanks for the reply, but I need that span to cover **only** the image (it should be the same size and position of the image), not the entire div (e.g. the div can be 600px wide and the image 100px wide, so the span needs to be only 100px wide). I hope this clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Can you write an immediate container around the image?

Comment: @Matthew: I'm already writing an immediate container around the image (that's the div that holds the image and the span), but for some reasons I'd like to keep it the it is now (div holds everything, span covers the image). Please check out the update to the question, as it should make the issue clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your `span` is positioned as absolute therefore it can't be floated left or right.

**Here's my versions for it:**

**A)** http://jsfiddle.net/6zQp3/47/

**B)** http://jsfiddle.net/6zQp3/49/

Now you can position the img + span anywhere.

Comment: I've updated the question as I don't think I've explained my issue clear enough. Unfortunately, the solution you've provided changes css of the image and I cannot do that. Thanks for help.